# React/Redux/Thunk form data flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

after several video courses and I'm confused about how to manage data on the form using React/Redux and Thunk.

I want all data on the form to be local and to be written to the store on the "Save" button press. So I'm not using any Formik nor any similar library.

As I have understood, all data should come from reducers, thus my reducer is sending an initial empty object to `mapStateToProps`. Now when I should pass data from props to the component's local state?

I need to do it before `componentDidMount` because my inputs are bound to the data object in the state. The constructor isn't a good place either.

Can I do directly:

```
state = {
  data: this.props.data,
};
```

Or maybe rather?:

```
state = {
  data: {...this.props.data}
};
```

And when it is an edit form, I call an API in the `componendDidMount`, how do I refresh data on the form from API? Is this correct?:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.data && this.state.data !== this.props.data) {
    this.setState({ data: this.props.data });
  }
}
```

Thank you for clarification

Comment: You shouldn't map your props to state. This will cause some trouble, once props change from outside of your component and you have to figure out what to update inside your local state. Have you considered using [Redux Form](https://redux-form.com/) yet? If you'd like to have an initial state, check out [this example](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/initializefromstate/)

Comment: But I don't want to change the store (redux) state directly from the input fields.. As I said I want to change to redux state when the Save button is clicked.

Comment: Think of your redux store as a cached version of your database. When you create an edit form, you make a copy of your data and mutate it either locally inside the form components state, or using Redux Form, which will also create a copy (using initialValues). When the user submits the form, you trigger an action, which will update the data in your database and then also updates your store (like when your data was fetched initially)

Comment: Ok, I was playing with it a little bit now and if I understand it correctly - form data are kept in a special redux module called `form`, replacing a component local state, thus separately from a business objects in redux store (received e.g. from API) and on submit I can push it to the store "real" data, right?